# Adding text in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

how can I add text into circle from var data? I mean from label?

My code:

```html
<!Doctype html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <title>Dobble</title>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
       </head>

       <body>
           <div id="canvas"></div>
           <script type="text/javascript">
              var w = 640,
                  h = 480;

              var data = {
                 name : "root",
                 children : [
                  { name: '1', size: 100, label: 'someText' },
                  { name: '2', size: 85, label: 'someText' },
                  { name: '3', size: 70, label: 'someText' },
                  { name: '4', size: 55, label: 'someText' },
                  { name: '5', size: 40, label: 'someText' },
                  { name: '6', size: 25, label: 'someText' },
                  { name: '7', size: 10, label: 'someText' },
                 ]
              }

              var canvas = d3.select("#canvas")
                 .append("svg:svg")
                 .attr('width', w)
                 .attr('height', h);

              var nodes = d3.layout.pack()
                 .value(function(d) { return d.size; })
                 .size([w, h])
                 .nodes(data);

              nodes.shift();

              canvas.selectAll('circles')
                  .data(nodes)
                 .enter().append('svg:circle')
                  .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
                  .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
                  .attr('r', function(d) { return d.r; })
                  .attr('fill', 'white')
                  .attr('stroke', 'grey');

           </script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is creating an g element (see [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/g-element.html) for more detail), it contains a circle and text.
Let's see my example:

**EDIT**:

Rotate the text inside circle:

- To rotate the text but keep position, you can use transform then inside it we calculate the position and radians to rotate

  ```
               .attr('transform', function(d, i){
                    var distance = d.r - 15;
                    // Converts from degrees to radians.
                    Math.radians = function(degrees) {
                      return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
                    };

                    var degrees =-90;
                    var xText = d.x - Math.cos(Math.radians(degrees))*distance;
                    var yText = d.y - Math.sin(Math.radians(degrees))*distance;
                    return "translate(" +xText + "," + yText + ") rotate(" + degrees+ ")";
                });
  ```

```js
                   var w = 640,
                      h = 480;
        
                  var data = {
                     name : "root",
                     children : [
                      { name: '1', size: 100, label: 'someText' },
                      { name: '2', size: 85, label: 'someText' },
                      { name: '3', size: 70, label: 'someText' },
                      { name: '4', size: 55, label: 'someText' },
                      { name: '5', size: 40, label: 'someText' },
                      { name: '6', size: 25, label: 'someText' },
                      { name: '7', size: 10, label: 'someText' },
                     ]
                  }
        
                  var canvas = d3.select("#canvas")
                     .append("svg:svg")
                     .attr('width', w)
                     .attr('height', h);
        
                  var nodes = d3.layout.pack()
                     .value(function(d) { return d.size; })
                     .size([w, h])
                     .nodes(data);
        
                  nodes.shift();
        
                  var enterEl = canvas.selectAll('circles')
                      .data(nodes)
                     .enter().append("g");
                     
                     enterEl.append('svg:circle')
                      .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
                      .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
                      .attr('r', function(d) { return d.r; })
                      .attr('fill', 'white')
                      .attr('stroke', 'grey');
                      
                  enterEl.append('text')
                  .text(function(d){ return d.label })
                  .style("font-size", function(d) { return Math.min(2 * d.r, (2 * d.r - 8) / this.getComputedTextLength() * 13) + "px"; })
                  .attr("dy", ".35em").attr('transform', function(d, i){
                      var distance = d.r - 15;
                      // Converts from degrees to radians.
                      Math.radians = function(degrees) {
                        return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
                      };

                      var degrees =-90*i;
                      var xText = d.x - Math.cos(Math.radians(degrees))*distance;
                      var yText = d.y - Math.sin(Math.radians(degrees))*distance;
                      return "translate(" +xText + "," + yText + ") rotate(" + degrees+ ")";
                  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='canvas'></div>
```

Comment: basically, I care that the text was on the center :/

Comment: It bases on your calculation like the way you add circle :|

Comment: So, how can I "center" text in this example? https://pastebin.com/HhLEvmq4

Comment: Thank you very much! You make my day broo

Comment: I have last question. It is possible to rotate text? I'm trying to rotate, But rotates with respect to the whole canvas and I want to rotate only text.. broo

Comment: Okay. See my edit agains and if it helpful, let's take a upvote :)